# how to insert expiry date column if use date data type?

Tags: sql, date, datetime, stored-procedures

```
create table Products
(
    ProductID int primary key not null,
    Name varchar(50)not null,
    Unitprice money,
    ExpiryDate date
)
```

My stored procedure

```
alter procedure stp_products_insert
    (@productid int,
     @name varchar(50),
     @unitprice money,
     @expiry date)
as
begin
    insert into Products(ProductID, Name, Unitprice, ExpiryDate) 
    values(@productid, @name, @unitprice, @expiry)
end
```

What date format should be entered here 20170810 for

```
exec stp_products_insert 123, 'goldwinner5kg', 150, ?
```

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? It often does make a difference whether you're using MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQL Server or IBM DB2 - or something else even. Please add a relevant tag to your question!

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding 
Since ExpiryDate is DATE data type, you need to convert the literal into DATE using TO_DATE and proper format model. The syntax is:

```
TO_DATE('<date_literal>', '<format_model>')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
DATEADD(day, 1, GETDATE())
```

in place of date. This will insert the next day date and if you want to enter some other date pass the number of day in place of 1.

Answer (score 0):

You should add date as below :

```
exec stp_products_insert 123, 'goldwinner5kg', 150, '2017-09-04'
```

The above SQL Script is for MS SQL Server